Convert dates that are either date strings or Excel integer
I need to convert date strings from user-completed Excel forms, which can come in a variety of formats including the date as Excel integer (I know this could have been prevented, but wasn't). I want to convert the following to dates:
excel_dates <- tibble(string_date = c("2012-01-01", "42123"))

I tried:
excel_dates |> 
    mutate(
        date = ifelse(
            is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(string_date))), 
            as.Date(string_date), 
            as.Date(as.numeric(string_date), origin = "1899-12-30")
        )
    )

but this doesn't produce dates (apparently an ifelse() design).
I also tried using if_else() but this fails because it cannot check that the data types of the TRUE and FALSE results are the same--because one of them fails.
I'm looking for a solution that does not involve multiple nested if-else blocks or loops, and hopefully is vectorized.

"I'm looking for a solution that's relatively simple." What do you mean by "relatively simple", specifically?

@TylerH in the spirit of saving/improving the question (and based on the answers) I edited something in, see if that's better.

janitor::convert_to_date() is a function for handling these mixed format dates imported from Excel.
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)

excel_dates |>
  mutate(date = convert_to_date(string_date))

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  string_date date      
  <chr>       <date>    
1 2012-01-01  2012-01-01
2 42123       2015-04-29


Instead ifelse try if
library(dplyr)

excel_dates %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(new = if(grepl("-", string_date)) {
    as.Date(string_date)} else {
    as.Date(as.numeric(string_date), origin="1899-12-30")}) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  string_date new       
  <chr>       <date>    
1 2012-01-01  2012-01-01
2 42123       2015-04-29


Nice use of rowwise() (not very efficient though)

This is longer than I wanted and throws a warning (because I guess it tries excel_numeric_to_date() on every entry?), but does produce the right output:
library(dplyr)
is_num <- function(x) stringr::str_detect(x, "^[0-9]+$")
excel_dates |>
   mutate(date = case_when(is_num(string_date)
           ~ janitor::excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(string_date)),
          TRUE ~ as.Date(string_date)))

You could write a cleaner conversion function like this:
date_conv <- function(x) {
   res <- as.Date(rep(NA, length(x)))
   has_dash <- stringr::str_detect(x, "-")
   res[has_dash] <- as.Date(x[has_dash])
   res[!has_dash] <- janitor::excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(x[!has_dash]))
   return(res)
}
date_conv(excel_dates$string_date) ## no warnings

You said "variety of formats including ..." The code here only deals with one format other than Excel format ...
